# Repeat function (unity3d/c#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, invoke, repeat

First of all, here's the code:

```
    using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

namespace UltimateSurvival
{

public class Radiation : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject radiationEffect;


    public EntityVitals Vitals { get { return m_Vitals; } }
    private EntityVitals m_Vitals;

    // Use this for initialization
        void Start() {

            InvokeRepeating ("OnTriggerEnter", 1.5f, 3.5f);
        }


    // Update is called once per frame
        void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            radiationEffect.SetActive(true);

                //yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);

                var entity = other.GetComponent<EntityEventHandler>();

                if(entity)
                {
                    var healthEventData = new HealthEventData(-Random.Range(7.0f, 23.0f));
                    entity.ChangeHealth.Try(healthEventData);
                }

                //yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);


        }


    }
    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            radiationEffect.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
}
```

What I'm trying to do is that I want this script to execute **OnTriggerEnter** every 3.5 seconds. As you can see, I'm using **InvokeRepeating** but it seems like it doesnt work. I've also tried changing **void OnTriggerEnter** on **IENumerator OntriggerEnter** and then yield return new **WaitForSeconds(5);** - It didn't work either. I'm really confused D: Please help!

Comment: OnTriggerEnter doesnt seems to be IENumerator on your code. Take a look at http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/350721/c-yield-waitforseconds.html

Comment: @iamIcarus read what I said after the script.

> I've also tried changing void OnTriggerEnter on IENumerator OntriggerEnter and then yield return new WaitForSeconds(5); - It didn't work either.

Comment: Unity messages (Start, Update, OnTriggerEnter, OnDestroy, ....) should not be called **manually**. These messages are called by Unity itself. In your case, it **does not make sense** to call it by yourself since you don't know when a rigidbody will enter into your trigger.

Comment: Indeed. To further explain what @Hellium is saying; you're trying to run a method (OnTriggerEnter) which uses the colliding trigger (`Collider other`) to. You're not specifying any `Collider other` in your InvokeRepeating. Please explain what you're trying to solve so you can avoid the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You never want to manually run OnTriggerEnter, so if you're doing that you're trying to solve something in a bad way.

Comment: It seems like you try to solve the issue of draining HP if the character is inside radiation area. I'll show you how this can be done!

Comment: yes id agree ontriggerenter is collider dependent and therefore a physics engine triggered event. if you want to repeat the trigger, you have to put an invisible object on the trigger at a repeating interval, else invoke the action done by trigger isntead.

Comment: @Fredrik please do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're trying to solve the problem of draining HP from the player if player is inside the area of radiation. This is a solution that will use most of your current code, but is not neccesarily the best code. I'd also like to inform you of [OnTriggerStay](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerStay.html), which

> is called once per frame for every Collider other that is touching the trigger.

and can also be used to solve this problem. I'm going to use your already declared OnTriggerEnter and OnTriggerExit to damage every player inside area every 3.5 seconds.

```
public GameObject radiationEffect;
public EntityVitals Vitals { get { return m_Vitals; } }
private EntityVitals m_Vitals;

// Declare a list that will contain the players.
List<GameObject> playersInArea = new List<GameObject>();

// Use this for initialization
void Start() {
    InvokeRepeating ("DamagePlayers", 1.5f, 3.5f);
}

void DamagePlayers() {
     foreach (var player in playersInArea) {
         var entity = player.GetComponent<EntityEventHandler>();

         if(entity)
         {
             var healthEventData = new HealthEventData(-Random.Range(7.0f, 23.0f));
             entity.ChangeHealth.Try(healthEventData);
         }
     }
}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        playersInArea.Add(other.gameObject);
        radiationEffect.SetActive(true);
    }
}

void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        playersInArea.Remove(other.gameObject);
        if (playersInArea.Count == 0) {
            radiationEffect.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Something like that should work. If you only have 1 player it should work all the same, but this supports multiple players. Let me know if you have any further issues.

Comment: That worked, except I had to add " using System.Collections.Generic;"

Answer (score 0):

You have problems calling your method using `InvokeRepeating` because of two reasons:

- `InvokeRepeating` can not be used with method that have parameters: you probably have the *Trying to Invoke method: [...] couldn't be called.* message in your console.
- `OnTriggerEnter` is a method that is automatically called by Unity when the gameobject's collider is set as *Trigger* and another collider enters it: as @Hellium said, calling such methods manually is a bad idea (same as calling `Start` or `Update` manually: this can happen but really doesn't make sense in most of the scenarios).

*Hope this helps,*